# Search by Value K-V Database with high speed

Tags: java, database, spring, redis, nosql

I stucked with solving this issue.

My project needs to store a lot of K V data( where K is id and Value some example MyData class) and get it by id from DB with good speed. After 3 days this Data must be expired(removed from DB).

According to this, I read a lot about Redis and we Start to use it.
We don't have a problem with RAM :) So everything was okay. Our load is 1 000 000 of records in Redis per 24h. So after 72h we have around 3 000 000  of records.

The problem is that we want to create a simple analytics service that will count and analyze data According to DataStructure(values of fields).
I found that Redis operations, such SCAN are not supporting Search by Value. Only By Key.

I found one little solution: is to concatenate some values of fields into Key( example "MyData:id7123718238,w788"). Sounds good, but if we need all custom querys we need to expose all values to Key, So it's bad.

please, someone, suggest me other solution or just recommend me other DataBase types for this.  Thanks

Comment: See http://redisearch.io

Comment: @GuyKorland Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterating over large amounts of data in Redis doesn't look like a good approach. If you want to stick with Redis even for analytics, make indexes and support them: [Secondary indexing with Redis](https://redis.io/topics/indexes)

However, if you plan to scale, it might be better to split your data flow into Hot Storage (Redis) and Analytics (any fast analytics DB). Write into both of them and query what is more appropriate in a given situation.

Comment: Thanks. What do you think about RediSearch? Is it possible to build analytics using such SearchEngine?

Comment: @MykhailoVoloshyn I don't know much about RediSearch. It is a search engine, what do you want to search with it? What king of analysis do you want? Have in mind, that Redis is not very good at iterating large amounts of data (it will block inserts). `Tarantool` would be more appropriate if you need both fast K-V and large queries in one tool. But with a standalone analytics DB you will get much more.

Comment: @MykhailoVoloshyn RediSearch provides you an easy way to set a secondary index an efficiently scan it.